# How unique MAC ID is generated for the each card?

Tags: macos, hardware-id

I was wondering that how can all different network devices have different MAC ID's.

is it hardcoded separately for each device ? (extremely unlikely..since in production nobody would like to change the code and recompile and load the program...)
or
a switch is used to set the address 
or
is it loaded from the ROM ?
or something else ..

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Each manufacturer gets an [OUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier) and programs the OUI + a unique number in nvram on the device during manufacturing. (And probably some hardcodes it, and others do something else) However this is offtopic here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Technically it should be unique. Practically very often it's not the case.

Comment: @zerkms 'very often', citation?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/268006/are-mac-addresses-unique-when-coming-out-of-the-factory

Comment: @scary_jeff it was yesterday someone in my twitter feed complaining they received a bunch of motherboards that had identical MACs. In the discussion there were even more people who confirmed they've had the similar experience in their career.

Answer (score 0):

Many networking interfaces use EEPROMs that come pre-programmed with EUI-48 or EUI-64. They use EEPROMs to store configuration settings and other data anyway, so they don't have any additional cost using the pre-programmed EEPROMs other than the chips ending up slightly more expensive per 1k. Programming each device with a unique ID would however incur additional cost.

For instance, [24AA02xE](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002124F.pdf) is an I²C SEEPROM with pre-programmed EUI-48/EUI-64 at standard addresses. [93AA46AE48](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005229B.pdf) is an SPI SEEPROM with pre-programmed EUI-48 that's directly compatible with LAN9xxx Ethernet Controllers.

I'm not affiliated with Microchip. I used their chips in a hobby project and noticed the datasheet mentioning the EUI-48 features.